# How to change the value of array key from inner array in following function code?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I'm having one array titled `$rebate_by_prod` that I want to modify. The array content is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [op] => preview
    [id] => 280
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [rebate_id] => 280
    [main_op] => edit
    [site_url] => http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/
    [rebate_image_url] => http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/images/rebates/rebate_images_by_product/2014/rebate_1412690625.gif
    [image_path] => rebates/rebate_images_by_product/2014/rebate_1412690625.gif
    [brand_id] => 134
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id_1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 214
                    [1] => 215
                    [2] => 216
                )

            [pack] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [units] => 51
            [amount] => 3.0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pack] => 1
            [quantity] => 2
            [units] => 49
            [amount] => 10.0
            [product_id_2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 214
                    [1] => 215
                    [2] => 216
                )

        )

    [title] => Three Olives Vodka
    [rebate_start_date] => 
    [rebate_expiry_date] => 2014-10-31
    [applicable_states] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
        )

    [multiselect] => 30
    [rebate_total_count] => 150
    [details] => Three Olives
)
```

Now I've written one function which is generating following output array after doing some necessary modification:
The function is as follows:

```
 function change_product_keys($reb_by_product) {
          foreach ($reb_by_product as $index => $sub) {
            if (is_array($sub)) {
              foreach ($sub as $key => $value) {
                if (strpos($key, 'product_id_') !== FALSE) {
                  $reb_by_product[$index]['products'] = $value;
                  unset($reb_by_product[$index][$key]);
                }
              }
            }
          }
          return $reb_by_product;      
        }
```

The output resultant array titled `$reb_by_product` is as follows :

```
Array
(
    [op] => preview
    [id] => 280
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [rebate_id] => 280
    [main_op] => edit
    [site_url] => http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/
    [rebate_image_url] => http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/images/rebates/rebate_images_by_product/2014/rebate_1412690625.gif
    [image_path] => rebates/rebate_images_by_product/2014/rebate_1412690625.gif
    [brand_id] => 134
    [1] => Array
        (
            [pack] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [units] => 51
            [amount] => 3.0
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 214
                    [1] => 215
                    [2] => 216
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pack] => 1
            [quantity] => 2
            [units] => 49
            [amount] => 10.0
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 214
                    [1] => 215
                    [2] => 216
                )

        )

    [title] => Three Olives Vodka
    [rebate_start_date] => 
    [rebate_expiry_date] => 2014-10-31
    [applicable_states] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
        )

    [multiselect] => 30
    [rebate_total_count] => 150
    [details] => Three Olives
)
```

Actually I want the manipulated array as follows :

```
Array
(
    [op] => preview
    [id] => 280
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [rebate_id] => 280
    [main_op] => edit
    [site_url] => http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/
    [rebate_image_url] => http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/images/rebates/rebate_images_by_product/2014/rebate_1412690625.gif
    [image_path] => rebates/rebate_images_by_product/2014/rebate_1412690625.gif
    [brand_id] => 134
    [1] => Array
        (
            [pack] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [size_id] => 51
            [amount] => 3.0
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 214
                    [1] => 215
                    [2] => 216
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pack] => 1
            [quantity] => 2
            [size_id] => 49
            [amount] => 10.0
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 214
                    [1] => 215
                    [2] => 216
                )

        )

    [title] => Three Olives Vodka
    [rebate_start_date] => 
    [rebate_expiry_date] => 2014-10-31
    [applicable_states] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
        )

    [multiselect] => 30
    [rebate_total_count] => 150
    [details] => Three Olives
)
```

I want the [units] key to be changed to [size_id] for each of the inner array. What change do I need to make to this current function that I've written for achieving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are assigning that inner array as a whole array directly, you need to create the new element with key `size_id` and unset `units` afterwards, before assigning the whole inner array to the outer one. If you are creating that inner array element-by-element, then you need to check whether the key of the current element you are about to create is `units`, and use `size_id` instead as key for the newly generated element.

Comment: @CBroe:If you would make the changes to the function code that I've written and post the entire function code as an answer it would be very useful for me as well as others.

Comment: Unlikely that this would be of much help to others, because your array structure is very specific. And I’m not gonna give you a copy&paste-ready solution – go try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
            function change_product_keys($reb_by_product) {
                 $reb_by_product_copy = $reb_by_product;
                      foreach ($reb_by_product_copy as $index => $sub) {
                        if (is_array($sub)) {
                          foreach ($sub as $key => $value) {
                            if (strpos($key, 'product_id_') !== FALSE) {
                              $reb_by_product[$index]['products'] = $value;
                              unset($reb_by_product[$index][$key]);
    ###############################
                              $reb_by_product[$index]['size_id'] = $reb_by_product[$index]['units'];
                              unset($reb_by_product[$index]['units']);
    ################################
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                      return $reb_by_product;      
                    }
```

use output of function as working array

Comment: You passed an refernce to this function. But I don't want to use reference.